# Updating HTML5 Progress Bar within XMLHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

Updating two HTML5 Progress Bar within XMLHttpRequest as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < times.value; i++) {
    xhr.open("POST", uri, false);
    xhr.send(payload);
    restSendBar.value += 100 / times.value;
    console.log(i + "th times");
}
```

and

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      restRxBar.value += 100 / times.value;
  }
};
```

In Firefox, the progress bar is updated as the for loop is executed. In Chrome the progress bar is updated after the for loop is complete.

Is this the correct way to update progress bar ?

Is this a bug in Chrome ?

Arun

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Chrome prioritizes the method calls differently than Firefox. Try updating the progress bar "out of band" by using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Update progress bar here
  restRxBar.value += 100 / times.value;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Some more surrounding code will help. 

Where will I set this time out ?

Comment: You will substitute it for your `restRxBar.value` call.

Comment: Still no change, the progress bar is updated after the for loop.